# Qt multipart post problem

Tags: qt, http, multipart, qnetworkaccessmanager

I need help with sending multipart post request. Main problem is that server doesn't recognise my request's post body part. Server side is working fine with android, but not with Qt and NetworkAccessManager.

Here is the code:

Here I make bodyPart to send with request (transferData is a QByteArray with some text):

```
postBody.append("\r\n--"+ boundary + "\r\n");
postBody.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth\" \r\n");
postBody.append(" \r\n");
postBody.append(auth + " \r\n");
postBody.append("--"+ boundary + "\r\n");
postBody.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload-test-data\" \r\n");
postBody.append(" \r\n");
postBody.append(transferData + " \r\n");
postBody.append("--"+ boundary + "\r\n");
postBody.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload-checksum\" \r\n");
postBody.append(" \r\n");
postBody.append(checksum.toHex() + " \r\n");
postBody.append("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
```

Here is headers:

```
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyApp 1.0");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary.toAscii());
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, QString::number(postBody.size()).toAscii());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "Content-Length" header after setting "Content-Type". Value should be something like `QString::number(postBody.length())`. (Edited: This didn't fix the problem).

Removing the extra space before the new line (\r\n) worked. Kindly change postBody.append(" \r\n") to postBody.append("\r\n")

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but changing size to length didn't work. More suggestions?

Comment: Lets also try removing the extra space before the new line (\r\n). Kindly change postBody.append(" \r\n") to postBody.append("\r\n")

Comment: That was it. Thank you Aziz, you saved my day. Put your comment as a reply, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Qt 4.8 there appeared [QHttpMultiPart](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhttpmultipart.html) class which does the trick.